# Adding a line to Textbox causes huge CPU load: how to optimize?

Tags: c#, winforms, performance, textbox

For some logging ouput, I have a Windows.Forms.Textbox which is updated via

```
TB.AppendText("some new text");
```

The method is hungry at redrawing the text field with >2000 lines inside, however it *feels* faster than with `TB.text += 'some new text`.

What should I use instead of Textbox to get quick inserts with low CPU load and fast refresh? I thought about Listbox but not sure if it will fit (however, DebugView's 'listbox' seems to be able to handle billions of lines without heavy load).

Comment: "billions of lines"? Really? You must have a whole lot of memory! Or very short strings.

Comment: I know programmers like to exaggerate but if you really have billions of lines of debug output, that might indicate an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ListBox or ListView would be much better suited for what you are proposing.

And if size becomes an issue, you can use ListView's VirtualMode to only load the items as needed, based on the user's scrolling.